# jQuery .Load and iis7

Tags: asp.net, iis, jquery

I am trying some AJAX calls for the first time. My site is hosted on my own IIS7, (http://*myUserName*:8078/HomePage.aspx).

Here is the jScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery1.4.2.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(LoadText);
function LoadText() {
    $("#Content1").load("data.txt");
}
```

"content1" is a content place holder.
My IIS is set to .net 4 too.

My problem is that the data.txt contents is never loaded. It is in the same directory as the page. I haven't got much experience in IIS so I am wondering if I am missing a setting or something.

Thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at what's getting sent back down to the browser in some dev tools like Firebug or IE9's dev tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you pass the `ClientID` and `file path` into the function as arguments, but the code below should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/jQuery1.4.2.js")%>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      LoadText();
   });

   function LoadText() {
       $("#<%= Content1.ClientID %>").load('<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/data.txt")%>');
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Drats. Scooped on getting the correct answer because of a morning meeting after I asked if it was a .NET control in a master page :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a single-tag XHTML-style script tag for JavaScript. Change your first line to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery1.4.2.js"></script>
```

For some reason, the script tag can't be shortened down to just a single tag, you have to have separate opening and closing tags.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, though it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Shot in the dark: Is '#Content1' an ASP.NET control, and are you using a Master Page? If so, the 'real' ID will have been changed by the .NET runtime.

Comment: Yes that's it! It is an ASP.net content place holder on a MasterPage. I changed the jQuery to target a div inside Content1 instead and now it works. Thanks alot all :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is data.txt in the root folder of your site? If so, the .load() method takes a URL so try "/data.txt"

Answer (score 0):

LoadText() is a function. Try:

```
 $(document).ready(
     LoadText();
 );
```

Also I would suggest using lower camel case for function names. Upper camel case functions as in LoadText() suggests by convention that it is a contructor.

```
 $(document).ready(
     loadText();
 );
```

You can also log something in the loadText() function to verify that it actually gets executed.

```
function loadText() {
    $("#Content1").load("data.txt");
    console.log('tried to load data.txt');
}
```

Comment: FYI $(document).ready(LoadText) is perfectly legal and will fire the function, just without the ability to pass any parameters. All jQuery events can be set up to fire a single function in that manner.

Comment: I thought so too. But then I observed this: http://jsfiddle.net/wsVAC/6/ Can you exaplain?

Comment: Calling a function's name with the parathesis just returns a reference to that function. Add this to your Fiddle: var t = LoadText;
t(); You will then see "fired fired" in the output. HOWEVER, as I mentioned jQuery events accept a reference to a function as a parameter, which is why they WILL run the function, but this doesn't happen in regular JS.